# What is the difference between these two programs?

Tags: c++

What are the differences between these two programs? For the first program I got an output of 9 and for the second program I got an output of 10.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // So we can see cout and endl

int main()
{
    int x = 0; // Don't forget to declare variables

    while ( x < 10 ) { // While x is less than 10
        cout << x << endl;
        x++; // Update x so the condition can be met eventually
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // So we can see cout and endl

int main()
{
    int x = 0; // Don't forget to declare variables

    while ( x < 10 ) { // While x is less than 10
        x++; // Update x so the condition can be met eventually
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Line 10 and 11 are exchanged.

Comment: @Fozi hahaha, lovely answer

Comment: Again, `001110101` and `jkfbvafdsf` are _codeS_, but `int main(void) {}` is _code_.

Comment: Compile and run both and see the difference.

Comment: top, you print before you increment, so the result of last increment is never printed.

Comment: step through with a debugger and watch the value of x

Comment: Add a 3rd version, with cout both before and after "x++;'

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I don't get it

Comment: @pm100 I did ,I saw the ouptut but then I do not understand it.

Comment: @Arkadiy Why for the 2nd case the x won't stop at 9 before it run the next increment ?

Comment: @axiac I did,but I still don't get it

Comment: @Fozi Thanks for the humor lol

Comment: @SuperKhew: I don't see the humor in Fozi's comment.  It is simply the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code block you are outputting x then adding to it so it will output 0-9. In the second code block you are adding 1 to x before you output it so it will give you outputs 1-10. It's based on where you put the `x++` in relation to the output statement

Comment: You meant that the value only will be checked with the condition after it is printed out?

Comment: @SuperKhew A `while` loop evaluates the condition *once before the beginning of each loop iteration*. It doesn't evaluate the condition *continuously while executing statements inside the loop body*, so it won't interrupt in the middle of the loop body. So yes, the value will only be checked after it's been printed (after that iteration of the loop body is finished, and it checks whether it should loop again).

Answer (score 3):

Output of first is 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.  Output of second is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

Comment: Damn you. You broke my sarcasm detector.  Good job answering what was asked, but not what OP really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you write the number out and then increase the variable, whereas in the second one you increase the value at first.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the order (obviously). In the first while loop, when `x` is 9, it prints it, increases it and doesn't pass the condition and does not enter the loop again.

In the 2nd case, when `x` is 9, it increases it to 10 and then prints it, and then leaves the loop. It's just common sense. The second loop therefore skips the number 0, and prints till 10.

**First loop** : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

**Second loop** : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: The value only checked with the condition after it is printed?Why the 2nd code won't stop at 9 if the condition is x<10 ?Yes,I know that for the 2nd case the x is increased first and just printed out.When the x is being added from 8 to 9,why wouldn't it just stop ?

Comment: Beacuse 9 < 10, and it'll do a loop once more, right?

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet prints the value of the variable and then increments it. This means the value of the variable after the last incrementation will not be printed.

The second snippet increments the variable and then prints it. This means that it will not print 0. The value it was initialized as.

Comment: The value only will checked with the condition after it is printed out?